# Self Hosting and IHttpHandler (ashx service)

Tags: c#, ashx, ihttphandler, self-hosting

I need to self host (in a windows process out of IIS) an existing .ashx service.
The service implements an IHttpHandler.

Comment: flagging this for not being a question.. an quite vague..

Comment: An .ashx handler can be hosted on IIS easily. Now I would need to host in a windows process, as we may self host for instance WCF services. Here how to self host a wcf service:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost(v=vs.110).asp. So my question is how selfhost an .asax handler?